# How do I synchronize a variable number of channels in Go?

Tags: go

I am testing out concurrency in Go by writing a client (in the form of a web server) that makes many requests to a web server and then returns how long it took to make those requests.  Basically a benchmark tool.

Here is to code I am using currently: [main.go](http://pastebin.com/yE3BUbZQ)

I know my code has many flaws but the one I am concerned with at the moment is how much effort it takes test how performance would change if I add more go routine calls.  In the **CallSync** function I have to keep adding on to this massive select statement and to the massive list of calls to the func that starts the go routine.  I know there must be a better way.  I probably don't even need to synchronize like I am right now, but if I did how could I do this in a more flexible way?  I want to have code where I can specify the number of "go routines" to call and it will call that the routine that number of times and synchronize with all the associated channels without having to hard code it all.

Comment: why not use one channel for all(c1...cN). you can write one channel in multiple go routine.

Comment: I know you said you're aware of many flaws; but two important ones you might not know about that I'd like to point out. First, remove the `default:` case of your `switch`; it makes it a non-blocking busy loop rather than blocking until there is something to read. Second, when `http.Get` returns an error you need to put a return in your `if err != nil` block since `resp.Body.Close()` will panic since `resp` will not be valid.

Comment: FYI, here's a "cleaned up" version based on [OneOfOne's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30905234/55504): https://play.golang.org/p/5ai9Cbi9Rx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @JiangYD suggested, it's easier to just use one channel:

```
type resp struct {
    id string
    i  int
}

func Async(url string, c chan<- resp, id string, count int) {
    cnt := 0
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        GetPage(url)
        cnt = cnt + 1
        if cnt == 50 {
            c <- resp{id, i}
            cnt = 0
        }
    }
}

func CallSync(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t0 := time.Now()
    ch := make(chan resp, 20)
    for i := range [20]struct{}{} {
        go Async("http://localhost:8080/", ch, fmt.Sprintf("ch%02d", i), 2000)
    }
    count := 0
    for count < 4000 {
        select {
        case r := <-ch:
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", r)
        default:
        }
    }
    t1 := time.Now()
    diff := t1.Sub(t0)
    num := diff.Nanoseconds() / int64(time.Millisecond)
    msec := float64(num) / 1000
    reqsec := float64(count) / msec
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v requests\n", count)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Performed in %v\n", diff)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "At a rate of %v (requests/sec)\n", reqsec)
}
```

Another approach is to use [`reflect.Select`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Select) but that would just slow things down.

Comment: If you do want to keep a channel per for some reason, you can take a look at https://godoc.org/github.com/eapache/channels for some patterns to gather the results of multiple channels; in particular probably the `Multiplex` function is fairly close to what you're looking for.

Comment: After seeing the 20 added to the make statement i realized I needed to buff up on channels.  I am pretty sure I get it now but just to be clear, you could remove that extra parameter from the make and it would still work but would be less efficient since the senders would always have to block to wait to send, correct?  By creating a buffer the same size as the number of go routines you started, you essentially will never have the channel block on the sending end?  Also could you describe what the for loop with the range is saying in "range [20]struct{}{}"? Anything beyond loop 20 times?

Comment: @Fyndor correct, the "20" is a buffer for the channel, it will still work ithout it but the calls will block until you read the result, it can still block if the buffer gets filled and your reader is slow in processing (but it shouldn't happen with your example) and `for i := range [20]struct{}{}` is a fancy way of doing `for i := 0; i < 20; i++`, it creates an array of 20 `struct{}` elements and loops on them, `struct{}` is special and uses 1 byte of memory at most.